# A slightly complicated differential problems that needs help

Tags: calculus

I have totally forgotten how to do calculus and recently I am taking a course that requires me to solves some differential problems and I am stuck at this:

$$
y = (x+1)^7 (2x+5)^2 (3x-4)^6
$$ 
find $dy/dx$

I am just not sure if I have to expand everything (which I believe I shouldn't) or is that just chain rule and product rule?

Comment: Hint: $y=2916x^{15}+11664x^{14}-20655x^{13}-121473x^{12}+28485x^11+516843x^{10}+160267x^9-1142835x^8-728589x^7+1349385x^6+1259592x^5-722832x^4-1036800x^3+9984x^2+337920x+102400$ :)

Answer (score 2):

Just have a bit patience:
$$
(f g h)' = (fg)' h + fg h' = (f'g+fg') h + fgh' = f'gh + fg'h+fgh'
$$
and
$$
\left((a x + b)^c\right)' = c (ax+b)^{c-1} (ax+b)' = ac(ax+b)^{c-1}
$$
should suffice.

Comment: thanks! that's what I was trying to derive a few minutes and this confirms that!

Comment: And it follows inductively that you can do what you did on the first line for any number of factors

Answer (score 2):

$$y = (x+1)^7 (2x+5)^2 (3x-4)^6\\
\ln y = 7\ln (x+1)+2\ln (2x+5)+6\ln (3x-4)\\
\frac {y'}y=7\frac1{x+1}+2\frac2{2x+5}+6\frac3{3x-4}\\
y'=(x+1)^7 (2x+5)^2 (3x-4)^6\left(7\frac1{x+1}+2\frac2{2x+5}+6\frac3{3x-4}\right)=??$$
In general:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\prod_kf_k(x)=\prod_kf_k(x)\sum_{k}\frac{f_k'(x)}{f_k(x)}$$

Comment: Nice shortcut!!

Comment: Is this valid for all $x \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Once you complete the computation, how do you check the answer at the end?

Comment: I think assuming $\mathbb{C}$ as domain of calculation, there is no problem.

Comment: @UmbertoP. not required here actually, required in "find the roots type" where ln is also involved. Only the last step here matters.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to take the absolute value of both sides first?

Comment: @GFauxPas Oh forget everything between Umberto and me. It really doesn't matter for the final result, whatever x may be.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Let $f = (x+1)^7\cdot (2x+5)^2, g = (3x-4)^6$, and use the product rule twice.

Answer (score 0):

Derive every factor in turn

$$
y' = 7(x+1)^6 (2x+5)^2 (3x-4)^6\\+
2\cdot2(x+1)^7 (2x+5)^1 (3x-4)^6
\\+6\cdot3(x+1)^7 (2x+5)^2 (3x-4)^5
$$